# Mongodb Two Phase Commits And Async Operation

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, promise, atomic

I have some questions after Read this Post:[Perform Two Phase Commits on Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)

Questions1: In the post, it purposed an example of back transaction. My question is what is the actual code look like? Is it just combine together all in to one functions like this? If not, then hwo to wen organize all the code in that post

```
var t = db.transactions.findOne( { state: "initial" } ) 
db.transactions.update(
   { _id: t._id, state: "initial" },
   {
      $set: { state: "pending" },
      $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
   }
)
db.accounts.update(
   { _id: t.source, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
   { $inc: { balance: -t.value }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
)
db.accounts.update(
   { _id: t.destination, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
   { $inc: { balance: t.value }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
)
db.transactions.update(
   { _id: t._id, state: "pending" },
   {
     $set: { state: "applied" },
     $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
   }
)
db.accounts.update(
   { _id: t.source, pendingTransactions: t._id },
   { $pull: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
)
db.accounts.update(
   { _id: t.destination, pendingTransactions: t._id },
   { $pull: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
)
db.transactions.update(
   { _id: t._id, state: "applied" },
   {
     $set: { state: "done" },
     $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
   }
)
```

Question2: Since Mongodb guarantee its operation is atomic when dealing with a single document, then Can I just wrap all the above blocks into promises and chain them together since each block only modify one document.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, you don't have to wrap anything, `update()` already returns a promise. You can run them all async like this

```
var t = db.transactions.findOne({ state: "initial" });

var query1 = db.transactions.update(
    { _id: t._id, state: "initial" },
    {
        $set: { state: "pending" },
        $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
    }
);

var query2 = db.accounts.update(
    { _id: t.source, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
    { $inc: { balance: -t.value }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
);

Promise.all([query1, query2]).then(function done(params) {
    console.log('all updates done');
}).catch(function catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**edit**

I quickly read the link to the mongodb doc and from what I understand, the two part commit is an attempt to recreate sql's transactions behaviour. It goes like this:

- create one document (the transaction) to log future updates to existing documents

  1. update the existing documents as needed (bank accounts in the example) << first phase
  2. update the transaction when the two accounts are updated correctly     << second phase

By reading the transaction's state you can know if the two (or more) accounts were updated correctly and are in clean state.

The code/pseudocode should go like this using promises:

```
// create the transaction
db.transactions.insert(
    { _id: 1, source: "A", destination: "B", value: 100, state: "initial", lastModified: new Date() }
).then(function (err, transaction) {
    // now you can start updating the accounts (first phase)
    var query1 = db.accounts.update(
        { _id: t.source, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
        { $inc: { balance: -t.value }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
    );
    var query2 = db.accounts.update(
        { _id: t.destination, pendingTransactions: { $ne: t._id } },
        { $inc: { balance: t.value }, $push: { pendingTransactions: t._id } }
    );
    // the two accounts must be updated together
    return Promise.all([query1, query2]);
}).then(function (err, result) {
    // accounts are update correctly, now update the transaction (second phase)
    // the transaction id must be stored somewhere in the code before
    return db.transactions.update(
        { _id: t._id, state: "pending" },
        {
            $set: { state: "applied" },
            $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
        }
    );
}).then(function (err, result) {
    // another updates on accounts if needed
    // ...
}).catch(function (err) {
    // deal with all errors here
};
```

The official docs uses *initial*, *pending*, *applied*, *done* states but you can use as many states you want, the minimum being two. So if something happens during the update of the two accounts, in another part of your application, you query to get all pending transactions and run the updates on the concerned accounts.

Comment: So which part makes the 'two phrase commit' special?

Comment: I didn't touch the "two phase commit" part, I'm updating my answer.